# Multiplying matrix A times multi-dimensional matrix "matrix-wise?"

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3d numpy array u, shape (k, m, n), and I am trying to compute a new array uprod, shape (k, m, n), such that uprod[j] = np.dot(A, u[j]), where A is a fixed matrix that doesn't depend on j at all. I can easily do this writing a loop over the inner-most index, but is there a faster/better way to do so?

Comment: U[j] is shape (m,n) son A is shape (l,m) . so (n,l)=(m,n),  i e m=n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) can do the job:

```
result = numpy.einsum('ij,kjl->kil', A, u)
```

You can also make it broadcast, so if `X` and `Y` are thought of as arrays of 2D matrices, the following call will perform an appropriately broadcasted `dot`:

```
result = numpy.einsum('...ij,...jk->...ik', X, Y)
```

For example, if `X` has shape `(3, 4, 5, 6)` and `Y` has shape `(4, 6, 5)`, then `result[1, 2]` would be an array of shape `(5, 5)` equal to `X[1, 2].dot(Y[2])`.

---

You can also do this with [`dot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html). `A.dot(u)` produces a result array with `A.dot(u)[i, j, k] == A[i, :].dot(u[j, :, k)`. You want a result array with `result[i, j, k] == A[j, :].dot(u[i, :, k])`; you can get this with [`rollaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html#numpy.rollaxis) or [`transpose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) with an `axes` argument.

```
result = numpy.rollaxis(A.dot(u), 1)
```

Where `einsum` makes broadcasting easy, `dot` for high-dimensional input is kind of like an outer product. With the same `X` and `Y` as before, if you set

```
result = numpy.rollaxis(X.dot(Y), axis=X.ndim-2, start=X.ndim+Y.ndim-3)
```

then `result[1, 2, 3]` would be an array of shape `(5, 5)` equal to `X[1, 2].dot(Y[3])`.